# Public Knowledge base for force.com site

Tags: community, force.com-sites, knowledge

A public Knowledge base to be created so that forec.com site visitors can view 
Knowledge Articles without any authentication as anonymous users and also vote for the articles. Is there any easiest way to do it for both desktop/mobile.

Answer (score 0):

> Public Knowledge for Mobile, Web and Facebook

This is a unmanaged package.  The look and feel can be customise by editing the VF page code provided with the package.

AppExchange URL : https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000059QxXEAU

Implementation Guide URL : https://appexchange.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P3000000P3UNSEA3

[image]